# Obtaining the "I Would Have Been Your Daddy" Skull on Halo 3

Tags: halo-3, achievements

I followed the guide at http://flamesoffeenix.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/halo-3-skull-locations/ in order to get the Skulls in Halo 3.

The last Skull mentioned is the "I Would Have Been Your Daddy" Skull.

> IWHBYD Skull Unlocks hidden dialogue
>   throughout Halo 3’s campaign.
>   Location: Currently, the ‘IWHBYD (I
>   Would Have Been Your Daddy) Skull’ has
>   yet to be found by the public. Only
>   members of the Bungie team know the
>   location of the final Silver skull in
>   the game.
>   The IWHBYD Skull has now been found!
>   Here’s how to grab it for yourself and
>   unlock that Hayabusa armour:
>
> Located on the level, ‘The Covenant’ –
>   After defeating the two Scarabs, head
>   inside to confront Truth and get to
>   the location with all 7 ring
>   holograms. Here you must jump through
>   the rings in a specific order to make
>   the skull appear.
>
> That order is as follows (1 is where
>   you came in, 7 is nearest Truth): 5 4
>   6 5 4 5 3 4
>
> Jump through them in the correct
>   sequence, and the ‘I Would Have Been
>   Your Daddy Skull’ will appear as if by
>   magic, right next to the bridge that
>   brings you over to the Prophet of
>   Truth.
>
> It’s worth mentioning that you may
>   want to take down Truth and the rest
>   of the Flood BEFORE tackling the jumps
>   though, it’ll make things a lot
>   easier.

I followed these instructions but nothing happened and I didn't see the skull in the location the instructions say it should be.

The instructions also don't mentioned whether there is any indication that you've done the steps correctly, is there any?

Do I have to jump through the rings in a particular direction as well as the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the order wrong.  It should be: `4 6 5 4 5 3 4`.

If it helps number 4 is the one with red on it.

The skull will appear on the light bridge (there is no other indicator) and you must finish the level to "save" it.

---

There are some caveats:

- Must play the level the whole way through (can't start from rally point)
- Must be on Normal or harder
- No, you can't try twice, if you screw up the order you have to restart the level.

Comment: Thanks! The order came from the website, so I was acting on misinformation!